# Why does dividing two decimal field values using Field Calculator return/write Integer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I have fields in my datasets such as HR60, HR70, HR80, HR90

When I tried to use field calculator using the following [HR70]/[HR60], all I got was 1, 2, 3, 4 as my values.

Last time I checked 1.14/2.24 is not 1 and 2.92/.69 is not 4.

In a map I did using field calculator using [ ]/[ ]*100 to get percentages and it let me do that so why this time am I getting whole #'s and not the appropriate decimals?

Comment: I am using ArcMAp 10.1.

Comment: Your output field might not be set as a double.

Comment: @user28383 Can you edit your data type (shapefile, file geodatabase, etc) into your original Question, please?  And also, include what the data type of the field you are trying to set this ratio to, and the parser you are using.

Comment: Well, my field preferences are set rounding to 2 decimal places.

Comment: This is a shapefile.

Comment: Please do not just respond using Comments, it is far better to revise your Question using its edit button each time you clarify another point raised in Comments.  That way potential answerers and future readers can view precisely what you are asking in one place without having to read a trail of Comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suspect the field you are calculating is in short or long integer
   format and thus will not be able to store decimals.  Check the
   field type by

   > right-clicking the field name > Properties... > type:

   You need to add a new field as either float, double or text and redo
   the field calculation.
2. Another thing to check is if your field has rounding preferences
   saved.  You can check this by

   > right-clicking on the field name > Properties... > Field Properties >
   >   Numeric... > Rounding.